# Python - iterate and replace (IPv4) with (IPv4 plus GeoIP)

Tags: language-agnostic

I am looking for an elegant way to parse a text file (i.e. a log file containing source and destination IPs and lots of other data) keeping each line intact, and replacing all IPv4 addresses with the same IP followed by a comma and the GeoIP country code of that IP.

I have tried doing this in bash, sed, perl, and python. I tried a hundred perl one-liners and never quite got it because substitution like `s/original/replacement/g` doesn't want to execute GeoIP lookup in the substitution field. For example:

`perl -pe 's/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/($1,system(geoiplookup $1))/g' < log.csv`

results in:

"srcip=(110.110.110.110,system(geoiplookup 110.110.110.110))"

instead of the executing geoiplookup.

I've tried this with backticks as well as exec, lots of different punctuation, with the same result.

In Python I tried some code that looks like:

```
rexp_ip = r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"
repl = { rexp_ip: rexp_ip+".test" }
---
  while line:
    line = i.readline()
    print(re.sub(rexp_ip, lambda m: str(repl.get(m.group())), line))
```

It seems pretty close but I'm not sure whether I'm on the right track here.

I would be open to bash, sed, awk, perl, python, or any other solution.

This seems fairly simple to me and I may be over-thinking it!

I am guessing I'm not the first person who has tried this and maybe I'm 'reinventing the wheel' here.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This would be very easy with [Prolog DCGs](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg) but learning Prolog is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved my own problem using perl with /e switch--

`` $ perl -lpe 's/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/(`printf $1;geoiplookup $1`)/eg' < log.csv ``